# I can't display image in a MVC view using Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I am using a webGrid to display data. Two columns are checkboxes. Instead of displaying the checkboxes, I want to display two .png images.

As you can see in the code, I've tried three different ways to do it.

I created a variable to hold the path, I used the string.Format, and I also put the path as a parameter in Html.Raw. None of them work.

I also added a Web.config file to the images folder, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Am I missing something? How can I make it work?

I'll appreciate your help.

```
  @{
     var checkboxEmpty = "<img src=\"~/Modules/Mime.Picor/Content/images/CheckboxEmpty.png\" />";
     var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: false);
 }

<div>
@grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "table table-striped table-condensed table-hover table-bordered",
headerStyle: "success",
columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Name", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink((string)item.Name, "Details", "LoadList", new { id = item.Id }, null)),
    grid.Column("DateIssued", header: "Issued Date", format: (item) => item.DateIssued.ToShortDateString()),
    grid.Column("DateRevised", header: "Revised Date", format: (item) => item.DateRevised == null ? "" : item.DateRevised.ToShortDateString()),
    grid.Column("DateSchedShip", header: "Schedule Ship Date", format: (item) => item.DateSchedShip == null ? "" : item.DateSchedShip.ToShortDateString()),
    grid.Column("TruckingCompany", header: "Trucking Company"),
    grid.Column("Comments", header: "Special Instructions", style: "col-lg-2"),
    grid.Column("Complete", header: "Cmp", format: (item) =>
    {
        if (item.Complete == 1)
        {
            return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"Image\"/></text>", Url.Content("~/Modules/Mime.Picor/Content/images/CheckboxFull.png")));
        }
        else
        {
            return Html.Raw(checkboxEmpty);
        }
    }, style: "text-align-center"),
    grid.Column("MakeReady", header: "Mk. Rdy", style: "text-align-center", format: (item) => (item.MakeReady == 1) ? Html.Raw("<img src='~/Content/images/CheckboxFull.png' />") : Html.Raw("<img src='~/Content/images/CheckboxEmpty.png' />")),
    grid.Column("AllDistributors", header: "Distributors", canSort: false, style: "col-lg-4"),
    grid.Column("DEL", format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "LoadList", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "delete16image" }))
))
```

Here is the rendered HTML for the picture path:

```
<text>
  <img src="~/Modules/Mime.Picor/Content/images/CheckboxEmpty.png></img>
</text>
```

Comment: Can you show us what URL actually gets rendered in place of that image? Raw HTML. The second one is clearly wrong - I think of the first one, using `Url.Content`. If you could also spin up F12 dev tools in Chrome/FF/IE to show any loading errors it'd be helpful.

Comment: That's the thing: I don't get any errors. It just doesn't display the image.

Comment: Can you see any errors in your browsers devtools? If the path is correctly rendered to the src attribute you should see your browsers attempts to fetch them.

Comment: There are probably several problems at play here. One is that the Url.Content is nor resolving the tilda. Another is those `text` tags. There is no such tag in HTML. A third is that your `img` tag should be self-closing. Most of that would probably be avoided by not using this anti-pattern of using `String.Format` to generate HTML. This seems to be forced by your usage of that web grid thing, that you probably also don't need. What's wrong with just using regular `table` tags?

Comment: @Bertrand. I appreciate your input. I borrowed the code from another post. The reason I used the webGrid is because of the convenience to sort by clicking the column name. What would you use instead of the String.Format line?

Comment: I told you, I'd remove that grid (if it's about sorting, you can get that with a simple specialized client script), and use regular markup instead of that Lambda and Format nonsense.